# ¿Por qué no me convierte de mayúsculas a minúsculas y viceversa? Java

Tags: java, string

Si se escribe “Bienvenido” deberá devolver “bIENVENIDO”.

```
public class MayusMin {

    public static void siEsMayuscula(String texto) {
        String tmp = texto;
        char letraNueva;

        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++) {
            char letra = tmp.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(letra)) {
                letraNueva = Character.toLowerCase(letra);
            } 
            else {
                letraNueva = Character.toUpperCase(letra);
            }
            tmp = tmp.replace(letra, letraNueva);
        }
        System.out.println("Conversión MayusMin: " + tmp);
    }

public static void main(String[] args)  {
        siEsMayuscula("Bienvenido");
    }
```

Y lo que me sale por consola es : Conversión MayusMin: bienVeniDO

No puedo encontrar donde está el error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! porque segun la documentacion, replace reemplaza TODAS las ocurrencias del caracter.. con lo cual si algo se repite, lo vas a volver a cambiar...

Comment: Perfecto, tenía una confusión con replace..Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que las letras se repiten, primero la convierte a mayúscula y luego a minúscula y por eso no obtienes el resultado, una solución de muchas que hay podría ser la siguiente

```
public class MayusMin {
public static void siEsMayuscula(String texto) {
    String tmp = texto;
    char letraNueva;
    String palabraNueva;

    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++) {
        char letra = tmp.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(letra)) {
            letraNueva = Character.toLowerCase(letra);
        } 
        else {
            letraNueva = Character.toUpperCase(letra);
        }
        palabraNueva += letraNueva;
    }
    System.out.println("Conversión MayusMin: " + PalabraNueva);
}

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    siEsMayuscula("Bienvenido");
    }
```

Comment: Gracias!! muy buena tu solución

Comment: De nada, estamos para ayudar, Pasa buen día

Answer (score 2):

Tu código deberia de verse tal que así :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class EsMayus {
    String siEsMayuscula(String texto) {
        char[] arr = texto.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(arr[i])) {
                arr[i] = Character.toLowerCase(arr[i]);
            }
            else {
                arr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        String resultado = String.valueOf(arr);
        return resultado;
    }   
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        EsMayus programa = new EsMayus();
        System.out.println(programa.siEsMayuscula("AlEx"));
    }
}
```

***EXPLICACIÓN DEL CÓDIGO***
Lo primero que hacemos aquí es crear una variable de caracteres del valor entrado por parametro (`texto`)
`char[] arr = texto.toCharArray();`

De esta forma, podemos realizar un bucle sobre este array para comprobar carácter por caracter tu string. Para esto, recorremos el bucle utilizando el siguiente bucle for :

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            /// NUESTRO CÓDIGO AQUÍ
        }
```

Ahora que vamos a comprobar cada carácter del String, creamos las condiciones de la siguiente forma :

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            // Si el caracter donde nos encontramos es mayusculas
            // se convierte en minusculas.
            if (Character.isUpperCase(arr[i])) {
                arr[i] = Character.toLowerCase(arr[i]);
            }
            // Sino es mayusculas quiere decir que es minusculas
            // por lo cual lo cambiamos a mayusculas
            else {
                arr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]);
            }
        }
```

Después de hacer las comprobaciones creamos la variable `resultado` que nos devolverá la String modificada.

Para convertir un array de caracteres a un String utilizamos la función `String.valueOf(array)` como hacemos ahora :

```
String resultado = String.valueOf(arr);
return resultado;
```

Una vez tenemos en `resultado` el String modificado, retornamos esta variable y desde el `main` llamamos a la funcion `siEsMayuscula`.

Cualquier duda escribe un comentario !

Comment: Porfavor, cualquier duda o aclaración que necesites escribe un comentario!

Comment: Muchas gracias, mi lógica estaba bien pero tenía una confusion con el método replace. Saludos!